# C libgit2 - listing files by commit

Tags: c, git, libgit2

I need to list programmatically, from Git, the files by commit. This is my code:

```
git_libgit2_init();
const char * REPO_PATH = "C:/Users/ki/test_repo";
git_repository * repo;
git_repository_open(&repo, REPO_PATH);

git_oid oid;
git_oid_fromstr(&oid, "08061b05");

git_tree *tree;
git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &oid);

size_t cnt = git_tree_entrycount(tree);
printf("tree entries: %d\n", (int) cnt);

...

git_tree_free(tree);

git_repository_free(repo);
git_libgit2_shutdown();
return 0;
```

The problem is, that the library throws an assert error, **tree.c** line 339. Any hint?

KI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git_tree_entrycount()` asserts when receives NULL tree pointer. You should check `git_repository_open()`, `git_oid_fromstr()` and `git_tree_lookup()` for return results. If any of them returns not 0 you can check error message with `git_error_last()`.

Comment: The git_tree_lookup returned an unchecked error. The ID used for lookup Is not the correct one. But I still stucked with my list.